# Strange SAM rules with functions

Tags: scala, function, single-abstract-method

What are exact rules for a function to be considered for Single Abstract Method conversion? In the following code there are two very similar cases, one is compiled, second is not, when compiled with Scala 2.12.4:

```
trait SAM {
  def apply(a: Int, b: Int): Unit
}

def callSAM(sam: SAM): Unit = {
  sam(0, 1)
}

def iAmSam(f: (Int, Int) => Unit) = {

  def lf(a: Int, b: Int) = f(a, b)

  callSAM(f) // does not work - error:
  //                          type mismatch:
  //                          found (Int, Int) => Unit,
  //                          required SAM

  callSAM(lf) // works. What is the difference?

  callSAM(f(_, _)) // works (lambda)

  callSAM((a, b) => f(a, b)) // works (lambda)
}
```

What is the reason `callSAM(lf)` works and `callSAM(f)` does not? I have found a mention in [Scala 2.12 release notes](http://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.12.0/#lambda-syntax-for-sam-types), which says:

> Note that only lambda expressions are converted to SAM type instances, not arbitrary expressions of FunctionN type

The `lf` does not look like lambda expression to me. Were the rules relaxed after 2.12.0? When `lf` is accepted, why `f` is not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`f` is just an object, and falls exactly under

> arbitrary expressions of FunctionN type

`lf` is the name of a method and when used as expression it's a shorthand for `lf _` which in turn expands to `(x, y) => lf(x, y)`, which is a lambda expression.

Comment: Out of curiosity: is there a reason for this limitation? What kind of evil would happen if arbitrary FunctionN expression were converted to SAM type instances?

Comment: I don't think anything particularly evil, this is just consistent with Java. It's also what Kotlin documentation says, but not how it actually works, IIRC :)